# SQL select where matching record exists and also when there is no matching record

Tags: sql

I am trying to return Account data from one table and financial Transaction date from another table. My existing query returns all the data I need when an Account has a matching financial Transaction, but I also need to return records (groups) from the Account table where there are no matching financial transactions...either because there are no financial transactions to begin with or because I am only looking for a certain type of financial transaction.

Here is my existing query and the results. I am also expecting (or trying) to see a row for each PaymentVendor where there have been no Collections.
`SELECT t.PaymentVendor, COUNT(t.AccountId) AS Accounts,  SUM(t.TransactionAmount \* -1) AS Collections from dbo.RawTransactionData t JOIN dbo.RawAccountData a on t.AccountId = a.AccountId WHERE t.TransactionDate \>= a.AddressDate AND t.TransactionType =  'FOR' AND t.TransactionStatus = 'U' GROUP BY t.PaymentVendor`

[image: query results]

Here is how my query started:

```
SELECT t.paymentvendor, t.accountid, t.transactiondate, 
t.transactionamount, t.transactionstatus, t.transactiontype
FROM dbo.RawTransactionData t
JOIN dbo.RawAccountData a on a.accountid = t.accountid
WHERE t.TransactionType = 'FOR'
AND t.TransactionStatus = 'U'
AND a.AddressDate IS NOT NULL
AND t.TransactionDate > a.AddressDate
```

I am hoping to find a way to return all account records that meet the criteria (even if there are no matching transactions)

Comment: Tip: Posting images of text limits our ability to help because we can't copy text (or test queries) from an image. So you have to rely on someone spotting the problem visually (or being generous enough to retype it all by hand).  To increase your chances of getting an answer, always post text - *as text* (i.e. table structure, data samples, etc..).   See [mre]

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will be sure to include the actual text in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LEFT JOIN in these scenarios, the LEFT table being the one you want all rows included:

```
SELECT t.PaymentVendor, COUNT(t.AccountId) AS Accounts, SUM(t.TransactionAmount * -1) AS Collections 
from 
   dbo.RawAccountData a 
   LEFT JOIN 
   dbo.RawTransactionData t 
   on t.AccountId = a.AccountId 
      AND  t.TransactionDate >= a.AddressDate 
      AND t.TransactionType = 'FOR' 
      AND t.TransactionStatus = 'U' 
GROUP BY t.PaymentVendor
```

Comment: The LEFT JOIN still only gives me the results where there is a matching Transactions

Comment: It will return rows from a, but as it is, the select does not have anything coming from a. Try adding a.accountid to both select, and the group by. What did you want to see for cases where there are no transactions? There will be no vendor. Also make sure that you don't have a where condition against the t table